# Having trouble with HappyLager

Tags: assets

I setup `HappyLager.dev`as per [these instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager), after setting up phpmyAdmin on a local dev box which was no small feat. I want to know why my Images/Assets are missing from the finished install.  Look:

[image: HappyLager - No Images]

I've checked my database import, which did succeed, in fact, I checked the entries/articles etc, and verified that the images do exist, and I copied the assets folder into apache:

[image: HappyLager Article - Skis]

The Article Entry does contain the image, ie skis, and every article/etc I glanced at is like this.  What did I  miss??

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with a local (default) installation of HappyLager: every image URL reads "/cpresources/transform/". I've verified the permissions on the assets folder and tried toggling the "generateTransforms" before page load setting in config, to no avail! Just can't get them to display and the system hangs when trying. Any ideas?

Comment: @NathanDHuening What are your permissions for `assets`?

Comment: 777. Or drwxrwxrwx, if you prefer. Totally puzzled!

Comment: @NathanDHuening Does 777 apply to the subfolders as well?

Comment: Sure does! Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the web inspector to look at the console log and see if it can find the images
2. Visit that image's location in the browser. If the location is correct, but it's not rendering, you probably need to check the image's file permissions. If it's set to anything lower than 644, you won't be able to see it. Set the image's permissions to 644
3. Make sure your assets folder and any subfolders are set to 777 so it can generate the image transforms

Comment: Thank You Sir, the permissions on the assets folder were 644.  Changing them to 777 and resetting thr owner to apache for good measure did the trick.  I stayed up til 4AM trying to figure this out, so sleep probably was needed too...

Comment: Any other ideas??